# How to add data in laravel request() healper from one controller to another without any perameters

Tags: php, html, laravel, request

Is it posible to add data to laravel request() healper globaly so that it will be accesible by any controller or service.

`class ABC extends controller {`

`public function setGlobalRequest() {`

`request('email') = "abc@mail.com";`

`}`

`}`

`class Xyz extends controller {`

`public function getGlobalEmailRequest() {`

`$email = request('email');`

`}`

`}`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand so far, you are trying to manipulate some data through different controllers.
I'm expecting that you have a model for your email, if so you can use the `pluck` method from the `Illuminate\Support\Collection` class.

Here's the [link](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-pluck) about `pluck` which is really neat for handling the same data over multiple controllers.

Comment: I am not trying to to access any model.
need to pass data in global request() healper go it can be accessed by any controller or services

Comment: Ok so that's not something you would want to do with Laravel, this isn't recommend. Instead you should look about middleware in order to filter the request the server receive, modify the data within the middleware.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right but i am trying to set this request() healper from test cases so it will be within the safe region of laravel.